# Need to find source path regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, gulp

I'm using gulp-replace because I need to find something in my code and replace it.

I have this function:

```
function configure($mdIconProvider) {
    $mdIconProvider
        .iconSet('navigation', '/src/images/material-design-icons/navigation-icons.svg', 24)
        .iconSet('action', '/src/images/material-design-icons/action-icons.svg', 24)
        .iconSet('content', '/src/images/material-design-icons/content-icons.svg', 24);
}
```

My regex needs to find `'/src/images or /images/` to replace it with the string I want because in my dev environment my path needs to be /src/images but in distribution it needs to be just /images/.

So I'll do:

```
gulp.task('replace-svg-path', function() {
return gulp
    .src(config.appConfigJs)
    .pipe(gulpif(global.isDist, replace('/src', '/images')))
    .pipe(gulpif(!global.isDist, replace('/src/images || /images', '/src/images')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
});
```

Of course that the first argument of the replace function needs to be the regex.

I really don't know much about regex, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace just `/src` the regex would be`/\/src/g`.
To replace `/src/images` or `/images` the regex would be `/(\/src)?\/images/g`

Comment: @FredericoJesus You need to pass `/g` modifier, I've updated my answer.